# jQuery automatically Scrolling to top issue

Tags: jquery, html

After adding a jQuery plugin I am not sure what's wrong but website is automatically scrolling to top every 3 seconds.

Can anyone help me find out where the issue is?

Link: http://www.mallaprojects.com/mt

Thanks

Comment: You have Gremlins in your browser, and they are trying to stay out of the water at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: This appears to coincide with the animation at the top of the page. After all, it is setting the location of the page to a fragment `...#...`

Comment: @adeneo - Are you still using Internet Explorer??

Comment: @lock there is another browser?

Comment: @lock - Nope, mine is called Internet Exploding, but I think it's just a newer version.

Comment: Just a stylistic tip: All that flare is needlessly distracting (and silly). Don't do that. There is a better way to display the needed information.

Answer (score 2):

It's related to a dependency of dasky... jmpress.  That tool is designed to control the user experience in atypical ways.  It does, however, have configuration options to disable hashing in the URL which may be what is causing the issue.  http://jmpressjs.github.io/docs/hash.html When the hash is updated, that often triggers scrolling to that point on the page.

Since you're not going for something on your website as crazy as what happens on the jmpress site, I'd suggest a different plugin choice.  Sometimes that's easier than trying to work with other's code.

2 side notes:

```
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You should never need to include the min and non-min versions at the same time.

And, consider not including all of your scripts at the top -- just those that are needed.  You'll speed load times and better the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Can't spot it exactly, but I'd be looking at dasky.eval.js and how it's taking scrolling away from users.
After that, I'd look at what your main animation code is doing. The top-scroll happens the moment the animation plays, like it's saying "WATCH ME!!"